# integral using residual theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have the following problem:
$$\int_C\cot z\ \mathrm{d}z,\ \ \ C(t)=2e^{it},\ t\in[0,2\pi]$$
my solution is:
$$\mathrm{res_0}\cot z=\frac{\cos(0)}{\cos(0)}=1$$
The circle only surrounds one singularity (0), so the result should be:
$$I=2\pi i\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}=2\pi i$$
But according to the (probably) correct restults in book it should be $4\pi i$. It seems so straightforward, that I don't see where could I've made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that I don't see where could I've made a mistake.

You didn't. The result is indeed $2\pi i$, since the contour surrounds only one singularity, and is traversed only once.

If it had been $C(t) = e^{2it}$, then the result would be $4\pi i$.